# C - How to synchronize access to a connection handle

Tags: c

Picture the scenario, I have an ADAPTER written in C that writes messages to SAP (calling an RFC).

The adapter is only called when a new message arrives in the "engine", so can have periods of no activity for up to 1 day or more. This is where the problem come in, the connection handle becomes invalidated on the "low level socket" layer in STANDARD code /or by some SAP parameters on SAP itself that may say "kill handles that are no longer active "

So what I do now is SPAWN a thread that "sits on top of the adapter" and PINGS SAP every 10 seconds or so. The issue here is that I am using the SAME connection handle for sending messages to SAP as well as for the PING / HEARTBEAT message.

SAP says for the RFC handle:

"**AN RFC handle can be used in several threads, but can only be active in one thread at a time. AN RFC handle of an RFC connection, created by one thread can be used in
another thread, but these threads have to synchronize the access to this handle.**"

But now I have tried using "pthread_mutex_lock" etc to make this work but it does not.

I have one GLOBAL "handle", and when my adapter SHARED LIB starts up I launch a thread like follows:

rc = pthread_create(&heartbeatThread, NULL, heartbeatThreadMainLoop, (void *)NULL);

And this thread just PINGS SAP every 10 or so seconds.

In a perfect world I would like the MESSAGING to SAP to take priority here, so the PING should totally wait until it is "quiet" and then start up again.

I have looked at links like:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html#SYNCHRONIZATION

But I actually want to LOCK / UNLOCK a whole section of code, so as I said if the MESSAGE is going into SAP the PING thread must wait....BUt if the PING thread is busy I would like to somehow INTERRUPT it and say "hey, I need that connection handle for messaging"...

What is a best practice "pattern" for this?

And help would be hugely appreciated

Thanks

Lynton

Comment: Show your code using `pthread_mutex_lock`.

Answer (score 0):

The whole architecture can be simplified by increasing the scope of ADAPTER.

Instead of its main loop waiting for a request indefinitely, have it time out after 10 seconds.  If it times out, do the wake up logic.  In either case (request or timeout), reset the timer.

That avoids the whole problem of sharing, and makes ADAPTER responsible for all interaction with SAP.